# Can't do this Rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I looked everywhere but I can't seem to make it work.

I have:

- domain/pageX
- domain/pageY
- domain/pageZ
  etc

BUT if I have domain/CODE/page I need it to be domain/page?CODE
Also if I have domain/CODE/page?p1&p2 I need it to be domain/page?p1&p2&CODE

`CODE` is a 2 character string which could be aa, bb or cc

Been trying stuff like:

```
RewriteRule ^aa/(.*?)$ $1&aa [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^aa/(.*)$ $1?aa [NC,L,QSA]
```

So I'm really lost on this topic, wasted many hours with no success, please enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been trying always these 2 ways, as in thinking when I have params and when I have no extra params

```
RewriteRule ^aa/(.*?)$ $1&aa [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^aa/(.*)$ $1?aa [NC,L,QSA]
```

But I removed the first and it actually worked just with the second one. Extra parameters are passed automatically so I just get the added aa, bb or cc as another parameter. Just need to declare one rule for each of them

```
RewriteRule ^aa/(.*)$ $1?aa [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bb/(.*)$ $1?bb [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^cc/(.*)$ $1?cc [NC,L,QSA]
```

Furthermore, if just aa is called without nothing extra, I added this rule for each:

```
RewriteRule ^aa(.*)$ index?aa [NC,L,QSA]
```

So it redirects to the index page and also passes the params + aa, browsing to aa/ goes through the first rule.

Leaving my answer if anyone encounters this same scenario :D